# What is the most efficient way of finding the index of the left/right-most unset bit in Java?

Tags: java, bit-manipulation, bitwise-operators

Let's assume that we have `int x = 371`, that is in binary format `101110011`. I want to find the index of the left-most unset bit (in this case 7), and the index of the right-most unset bit (in this case 2). What is the most efficient way of doing it?

Here's what I have:

```
public class BitOperatons {

    public static int setBit(int x, int i) {
        int y = x | (1 << i);
        return y;
    }

    public static boolean isBitSet(int x, int i) {
        int y = setBit(0, i);
        return y == (x & y);
    }    

    public static int findLeftMostSetBit(int x) {
        for (int i = 31; i >= 0; i--) {
            if (isBitSet(x, i))
                return i;
        }
        return -1;
    }

    public static int findRightMostUnsetBit(int x) {
        for (int i = 0; i <= 31; i++) {
            if (! isBitSet(x, i))
                return i;
        }
        return -1;
    }

    public static int findLeftMostUnsetBit(int x) {
        int k = findLeftMostSetBit(x);
        for (int i = k; i >= 0; i--) {
            if (! isBitSet(x, i))
                return i;
        }
        return -1;
    }

    public static1+ void main(String[] args) {
        int x = 
            (1 << 0) |
            (1 << 1) |
            (1 << 4) |
            (1 << 5) |
            (1 << 6) |
            (1 << 8);
        System.out.println(findLeftMostUnsetBit(x));
        System.out.println(findRightMostUnsetBit(x));
    }

}
```

If I'm not wrong, my current implementation takes linear time. Can we do better?

Comment: It's not possible to do better than linear.

Comment: @toto, this is not true, doh forgot, look at Hacker's Delight 5-3 (for example) (leading zeros, which is part of Integer.class)

Comment: @bestsss, OK if you mean machine instructions as suggested by flolo.  If you know of a sub-linear algo, I'd like to know.

Comment: @toto, no it's not assembler or CPU provided instruction. it is binary search instead of linear :). Seriously try to find a copy of Hacker's Delight (book) and check it.  I will post how to do leading zeros part. I'm sure even SO will have some stuff on.

Comment: @bestsss Yes, I was thinking about it right now.  I wanted to write it as an answer. Thanks.  Still better to use the Java API.  (Edit: just checked the code of `Integer.numberOfTrailingZeros` and it is binary search.)

Comment: http://graphics.stanford.edu/~seander/bithacks.html is an interesting article on this subject. Not all of the algorithms presented are suitable for Java, though.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are methods available in the Integer class.

`Integer.numberOfTrailingZeros(Integer.lowestOneBit(~yourValue))` would do it for the lowest one unset bit, for the highest it is a bit trickier as we first have to determine the highest set bit.

```
int leadingZeroBits = Integer.numberOfLeadingZeros(Integer.highestOneBit(yourValue));
result = Integer.
       numberOfTrailingZeros(Integer.highestOneBit((~yourValue)<<leadingZeroBits)
      -leadingZeroBits;`
```

Should do it for the highest unset bit.

And this may be faster than linear time as processors often have machine instructions to determine fast the leading/trailing zero bit (but not sure if the vm utilize them EDIT: I am now sure ;-).

**EDIT**: [It seems they added the use of asm intrinsics for leading/trailing zeros in 1.6.0_18, ID 6823354](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/6u18-142093.html)

Comment: hmm, indeed intrinsics look like a CPU instruction where possible.

Answer (score 5):

Below it's the source code of Integer.numberOfLeadingZeros. As pointed it's taken from HD (Hacker's Delight by Henry S. Warren, Jr)

The main idea is using binary search instead of iterating the bits, one by one. Please, check the book if you are interested in bit twiddling. It's a wonderful piece of art.

```
public static int numberOfLeadingZeros(int i) {
    // HD, Figure 5-6
    if (i == 0)
        return 32;
    int n = 1;
    if (i >>> 16 == 0) { n += 16; i <<= 16; }
    if (i >>> 24 == 0) { n +=  8; i <<=  8; }
    if (i >>> 28 == 0) { n +=  4; i <<=  4; }
    if (i >>> 30 == 0) { n +=  2; i <<=  2; }
    n -= i >>> 31;
    return n;
}
```

Comment: The implemented code in the Sun (Oracle) library is slightly different, but equivalent.

Comment: @bestsss: `numberOfLeadingZeros` is a more efficient implementation of my `findLeftMostSetBit`. However, I don't see how to use it for answering my question, that is finding the index of the left/right-most unset bit. If we have `0000000000000000000000101110011`, then I want to find the index of the left-most unset bit, which is 7, and the index of the right-most unset bit, which is 2. How would you do that? (thank you for recommending _Hacker's Delight by Henry S. Warren, Jr_: it seems a very interesting book, and I'll put it in my wish list :) )

Comment: @MarcoS, look at flolo's answer for some insight, this answer was targeting toto's remark in the comments, mostly. Paul Cager's comment also contains a very useful collection of C (can be ported to java too) bit twiddling hacks.

Comment: @bestsss: I see! ... so I should choose both yours and flolo's post as answers, but I can't. So, I'll pick flolo's as answer, but still upvote yours.

Comment: @MarcoS, I put it as community wiki for a reason. Still the point about HD, if you are interested in bit twiddling it's a prime source of ideas; the dance of the bits used to fascinate me when i was kid (doing assembler)